# How can I overpass syntax error at this code?

Tags: java, sqlite

I was working for my project , i crossed with syntax error while 
creating table. Could you help me?
Taking values from textfields , will use for considering attribute names

```
String ac2 = a2.getText();
String ac3 = a3.getText();
String ac4 = a4.getText();
String ac5 = a5.getText();
String ac6 = a6.getText();
String ac7 = a7.getText();
String ac8 = a8.getText();
String ac9 = a9.getText();
```

Taking values from combobox to determine type of attribute

```
String t1 = c1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String t2 = c2.getSelectedItem().toString();
String t3 = c3.getSelectedItem().toString();
String t4 = c4.getSelectedItem().toString();
String t5 = c5.getSelectedItem().toString();
String t6 = c6.getSelectedItem().toString();
String t7 = c7.getSelectedItem().toString();
String t8 = c8.getSelectedItem().toString();
String t9 = c9.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

My query to create table

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + tablename + "(\n"
            +"Name" +t1 + "PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,\n"
            +ac2 +t2 + ",\n"
            +ac3 +t3 + ",\n"
            +ac4 +t4 + ",\n"
            +ac5 +t5 + ",\n"
            +ac6 +t6 + ",\n"
            +ac7 +t7 + ",\n"
            +ac8 +t8 + ",\n"
            +ac9 +t9 + ",\n"
            +");";
 try(Statement stmnt = connection.createStatement()  ){
        stmnt.execute(sql);
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
```

I am using jdbc for sqlite , with this code I am aiming to create a 
table from user given values.

I am taking error unrecognized token("2TEXT") now.

Comment: Where's your syntax error? In the Java code or the sql statement? What's the error message?

Comment: Are you trying to name your table "TABLE NAME"? `TABLE` is a reserved word in SQL. That image is not particularly helpful.

Comment: I suppose that's not the full code, right? Where does the tablename come from? Is it empty? Did you select a database as the error specifies?

Comment: @ArifAkkas add space between attribute and type. edited my answer, please try it out

Comment: I took care for syntax error , thanks a lot.

Comment: Arif - Don't edit your questions to totally alter their meaning.  If you have a new question, ask a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

remove the last comma and add space between attribute and type

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + tablename + "(\n"
            +"Name" +t1 + "PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,\n"
            +ac2 + " " + t2 + ",\n"
            +ac3 +" " + t3 + ",\n"
            +ac4 +" " + t4 + ",\n"
            +ac5 +" " + t5 + ",\n"
            +ac6 +" " + t6 + ",\n"
            +ac7 +" " + t7 + ",\n"
            +ac8 +" " + t8 + ",\n"
            +ac9 +" " + t9 +");";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a number of actual or potential syntax errors.

- You have not put a space between the column names and the corresponding types.
- There is a trailing comma in the list.
- Any of the input names (`tablename`, `ac2`, `ac3` etcetera) could have a value that is an SQL keyword.
- Any of the input types (`t1`, `t2`, etcetera) could have a value that is not a valid SQL column type specification.

I suggest that you **print out** the SQL that you are building in `sql` ... and look at it carefully.

Comment: thanks a lot , could you help me for the next problem